# Identification of erroneous queries in ObjectGears

Tags: objectgears

Is there a way to check all the queries in ObjectGears? I can now display them only for particular models not all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

Create this query in ObjectGears. It will provide what you need.

```
SELECT m.Name AS Model_name, cd.Name, cd.Code, cd.Created, cd.Creator, cd.Modified, cd.Modifier, './QueryDetail.aspx?Id=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,cd.Id) AS URL
FROM ClassDef cd
  INNER JOIN Model m ON m.Id = cd.ModelId
WHERE 
  cd.isDirty = 1 AND
  cd.EntityType = 1
```